# Антимат на php?

Tags: php

Если в строке $str есть матное слово, то $str = "censored";. Возможно, с помощью preg_replace?

Comment: Нет, вы никогда не сможете найти все матные слова

Comment: @andreymal лучший ответ года!

Comment: А хоть какой-то вариант можно?)

Comment: P.S. плохие слова можете не писать)

Comment: `preg_replace('/\S+/', '[[censored]]', $str)` - само то

Answer (score 1):

Для всем известного слова из трех букв регулярка будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
m/(?:^|\W)((?:х|x|h|к|k|}{)\W*[уyu]\W*[йuyi])(?:$|\W)/ig;
```

Взято из публикации https://habr.com/post/101232/

Comment: Какого [[censored]] оно не работает? буквы я явно не хватает рядом с й

Comment: А ещё "сколько ни **кукуй**, лет не прибавится"